# Text selection visible in alert(), but not in html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a variable using `document.getSelection()`

This variable is well displayed if I use `alert()` but not if I use `html()`.

How can I make it visible with `html()`?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sentence").dblclick(function(){
        var selected_word = document.getSelection();
        $("#word_to_be_showned_in").html(selected_word);
        alert(selected_word);
});
});
```

```html
<p class="sentence">have a try</p>
<p>Selected word should appear here: <span id="word_to_be_showned_in">XXX</span></p>
```

Example (compatible with chrome): http://js.do/code/38012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getSelection()` returns an object, not a string. Add `.toString()` to get its text:

```
var selected_word = document.getSelection().toString();
$("#word_to_be_showned_in").html(selected_word);
alert(selected_word);
```

Fixed example: http://js.do/code/38017

Comment: thanks it works perfetly and I know why thanks to your explaination

Answer (score 1):

Add to the var a empty string and it will treat as string.

Example:

```
var+""
```

Live Demo of your code at http://jsfiddle.net/U5nWV/